# Updating constraints after rotating a UIView

Tags: ios, objective-c, autolayout, nslayoutconstraint, cgaffinetransform

I have a rectangular `UIView` whose edges are constrained to its superview. I need to rotate this view by 90 degrees, but then update its constraints so it stays correctly constrained to the superview. If I do

```
self.overlayView.transform = CGAffineTransformMakeRotation(M_PI * 0.5);
```

The view rotates, but the width and height stay fixed the wrong way round. Do I need to break the constraints and set them again so that the top is constrained to the superview's left, the left is constrained to the superview's bottom and so on?

Comment: call `[self setNeedsLayout]` and tell what is the result

Comment: `setNeedsLayout` doesn't make any difference unfortunately. I've also tried `[self.overlayView setNeedsUpdateConstraints]`. The problem is that I think `CGAffineTransformMakeRotation` isn't auto-layout compatible.

Comment: why do u need to update your constraints? your view should be set to being there after rotation i guess

Comment: Maybe  [self layoutIfNeeded] after setNeedsLayout will solve the situation.

Comment: @SahebRoy say I have a subview which is 200 x 300 and is contained in a superview of the same size, I wanted to be able to rotate that subview by 90 degrees and have it re-constrain to the superview as 200 x 300, instead of its rotated dimensions of 300 x 200.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Autolayout plays with the `frame` to do its thing. As per [the docs](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/UIKit/Reference/UIView_Class/#//apple_ref/occ/instp/UIView/transform), the frame is undefined when the `transform` is set to something other than the identity.

Based on [this](http://revealapp.com/blog/constraints-and-transforms.html), it would appear that this is fixed in iOS8 (and indeed they reference the above docs, noting that as of iOS8 `setFrame` method gets called on the transformed view).

Comment: Thanks for the link, very informative. Fortunately, I only have to support iOS 8 and above, but it appears as though what I was trying to do isn't supported by Auto Layout in iOS 8. Since transformations "no longer factor into Auto Layout's calculations", I have resolved it as per one of their suggestions, by constraining the container view but not the transform view. I still have to update the frames myself, but at least this gives the desire results. Thanks.